# Cross-thread communication and field-updating in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm having some trouble getting cross-thread communication/field-updating working properly in my VB.NET 2010 program. I'm trying to update a field on my main form whenever a thread that I've started throws an event. Here's a simplified version of my code:

My main form:

```
Public Class Main
    ' stuff

    ' Eventually, startProcessing gets called:
    Private Sub startProcessing()
        Dim processingClass = New MyProcessingClass("whatever")
        AddHandler processingClass.processStatusUpdate, AddressOf handleProcessStatusUpdate
        Dim processingThread = New Thread(AddressOf processingClass.process)
        processingThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub handleProcessStatusUpdate(statusUpdate As String)
        txtMainFormTextBox.Text = statusUpdate ' InvalidOperationException
        ' "Cross-threaded operation not valid: Control 'txtMainFormTextBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"
    End Sub
End Class
```

The class which raises the event:

```
Public Class MyProcessingClass
    Private whatever As String    

    Public Event processStatusUpdate(status As String)

    Public Sub New(inWhatever As String)
        whatever = inWhatever
    End Sub

    Public Sub process()
        ' do some stuff
        RaiseEvent processStatusUpdate(whatever)
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, the handler in my main class doesn't have access to the TextBox I need since it was triggered by a different thread (I think). I've tried a number of other approaches to get this working, including:

1. Moving the event handler to `MyProcessingClass`, and passing `txtMainFormTextBox` by reference (ByRef) to the class.
2. Having the actual thread start inside of `MyProcessingClass` instead of `Main`.

None of these have worked. Clearly there's a concept that I'm missing here. What's the best way to get this done? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the textbox on the UI thread by calling `BeginInvoke`.

---

You should use the [`BackgroundWorker` component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), which does all of this for you.
Simply handle the `DoWork` and `ProgressChanged` events.

Comment: The problem with `BeginInvoke` is that I can't pass agruments when I use it, so I can't use my `statusString`. I'll look into BackgroundWorker...

Comment: @Mike: You can pass arguments to `BeginInvoke`.  Just use an `Action(Of String)`.  However, you should use a BackgroundWorker instead.